# Instrument not connecting to Linux Server

Tags: linux

I work at a hospital and we just changed over to a new Linux server.
We are having trouble with one instrument that shows not connected.
The instrument vendor states to alert I.T. that the host is closed.

Our network guy can ping the new IP address and says it is connected. He was also able to trace the I.P.

We pointed this one instrument back to its old IP address and the device connects. The instrument is what we call a listening instrument. It only uploads data. We have other listening instruments and those had no problems with the switch.

We have restarted the server and detached and reattached the instrument. This is about all we can do from the laboratory perspective.

From a Linux perspective, are there any tips you can provide to diagnose the problem? I was reading up on "Verbose mode". Not sure if that is something to recommend.

The Network guy is new to Linux. Also, I'm just fishing for ideas. I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place. If not, please forgive me.

Any ideas would be grateful

Comment: First of all, we need more information about this "instrument", what it's trying to connect. Is it TCP/UDP? Do you know the port the server listens to? Are you able to `ssh` to the server? Are you sure the listening application is running?

Comment: I'd suggest getting in touch with the technical support provided for this "instrument". I mean, you're working in a hospital - this should be done professionally, I assume?

Comment: At a guess I'd say that the instrument has been configured with the IP address of the old server so that it can upload its information. You've replaced that server and it seems from what you write that you've allocated a new IP address for the new server. Therefore the instrument can no longer upload its data. I would _strongly_ suggest you contact the instrument's vendor support and get help

Comment: Thanks to all that tried to help. We found out the vendor did not fully investigate the problem. The instrument runs through a "secondary box" and that also holds an IP that needed updating. Our Network guy was able to monitor the traffic on the line and it looks like we were good on our end.